# Font Awesome : how to use Regular style icon?

Tags: css, font-awesome, elementor

I should like to insert a Font Awesome icon in Regular Style (far) and not in Solid Style (fas).
I don’t know how to change it : by default the Solid Style appears on the site.
The builder is Elementor.

Here is the [Font Awesome page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/file-alt?style=regular).
Here is my code :

```css
.ma-classe a::before {
    content: "\f15c";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: insert your full code!

Comment: If you go and inspect the different versions on the fontawesome page, then you will see that both use the same font family, but different font weights. The weights are also listed here, https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Comment: @Aahad Excuse-me, I don't have more that the above inserted code.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you ; I tried to change the font weight without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this in your HTML:

```
<i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
```

instead of trying to do it with CSS.

Comment: Thank you : but where must I insert this HTML code. Is there a way via the Elementor builder ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to use the Elementor builder. You would insert this code in for example the div where you want to have the icon. As you didn't provide a lot of code I can't really be specific here.